# Dealing with duplicates in message queue

Tags: message-queue, debouncing

Let's say I have high-load Q/A forum like stack overflow.
Imagine there are only two threads, First and Second.
Everytime when someone posts an answer/reply it causes two inserts into message queue. 
1. command for insert of the post/reply and 
2. command for rebuild cache of the given thread.

Let's assume, I have this snapshot of the queue in certain time:

```
0: insert First.1 answer
1: rebuild First
2: insert First.2 answer
3: rebuild First
4: insert Second.1 answer
5: rebuild Second
6: insert First.3 answer
7: rebuild First
```

A./
When processing the queue in step #1, is there any mechanism, that would help to realise, that there are yet rebuilds of "First" at #3 and #7 and so the #1 and #3 can be discarded and only the #7 can be processed?

B./
What message queue product (RabbitMq, Kafka, ActiveMQ...) could be best for this usage? The crucial property here is performance and scalability, since the application should handle > 100 000 req./s., with about 10% of writes (against 90% cache reads).

Thanks for any advice.
(not a homework, just simplification of too complex problem to describe in full detail)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the terminology you're looking for here is "debouncing."  If I'm the index rebuilder service, I may know that it takes 5 seconds for the index to be rebuilt. Thus there is a possibility of multiple messages arriving in the timeframe it takes to rebuild the index. A debounce routine will operate on a time constant, accepting many messages but producing one rebuild request per reasonable unit of time.

You'll have to write your own routine for this, or alternatively, it may be possible to utilize the semantics of `Rx` (reactive framework) to do this.

[Here is a resource](https://medium.com/mettle-adventures/the-magic-of-reactivex-debouncing-inputs-to-async-functions-f3d4d80ea68a) which probably touches on what you're trying to achieve, at least conceptually.

Comment: At the end, I ended up with some kind of "load balancing". Simplified, I have for start 3 consumers, each attached to it's "private" queue. Via Thread.id modulo number-of-consumers, I can ensure, that specific thread ends always in the same one-of-three queues and hence, this eliminates, that two consumers would operate / rebuild cache on the same thread in the same time. It is not perfect, but good enought for a while. Well, I didn't solve the problem with skiping unnecessary rebuilds. However thank you for introducing interesting concept to me.